# Finite subcover of pairwise disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following exercise:

Prove that if $X$ is a countable compact subset of $ \mathbb{R}$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}l \left({U_i}\right)<\varepsilon \text{      and }  X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}U_i$$ 
Use this to prove that any closed interval $[a,b]$ with $b>a$ is uncountable.

Now since any countable set has measure zero given $\varepsilon>0$, I can find a collection of open intervals $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l \left({U_n}\right)<\varepsilon \text{      and }  X\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$
Moreover, since $X$ is compact, I can find a finite subcover of open intervals $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^{m}$, such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}l \left({U_k}\right)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l \left({U_n}\right)<\varepsilon \text{      and }  X\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}U_k$$
But how can I find a subcover that is also pairwise disjoint?

Comment: You should be able to arrange that the original collection consisted of pairwise disjoint open intervals (by taking unions of intersecting intervals, perhaps). I also note that the application to the uncountability of closed intervals doesn't require the $U_i$ to be disjoint, since the measure of the union is less than or equal to the sum of their lengths in any case.

Comment: Ok so I have to arrange the original collection so that it becomes a collection of pairwise disjoint intervals. Then I conclude that if $[a,b]$ is countable then $m([a,b])\leq m(\bigcup U_i)\leq \sum l(U_i)<\varepsilon$ which is impossible for $\varepsilon<b-a$ right?

Comment: You can use the fact that any non-empty open set is a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pairwise disjoint sets let $\tilde{U}_1 = U_1$ and $\tilde{U}_j = U_j - \overline{U_{j-1}}$

Then, $\sum_{j=1}^m l(\tilde{U_j}) \leq \sum_{j=1}^m l(U_j) < \epsilon$ for all $m$ and $X \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^m \tilde{U}_j$ .

Comment: Thanks. Then I conclude that if $[a,b]$ is countable then $m([a,b])\leq m(\bigcup U_i)\leq \sum l(U_i)<\varepsilon$ which is impossible for $\varepsilon<b-a$ right?

Comment: $U_j-U_{j-1}$ is not in general open.